# pkg-config cannot find any package

Tags: pkg-config

I need to use latest version of pkg-config. So I build it from source with `--with-internal-glib --disable-host-tool`.

However, it cannot find any package without setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH. How can I make it behave like system installed one which contains all default paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you built from source using `autoconf` then according to `./configure --help`, there's a configuration variable for that:

```
  --with-pc-path          default search path for .pc files
```

You can find the search path for your system-installed version as mentioned in the man page:

> ```
>   pc_path
>           The default search path used by pkg-config  when  searching  for
>           .pc files. This can be used in a query for the pkg-config module
>           itself itself:
>             $ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
> ```

ex.

```
$ /usr/bin/pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

Then copy the result to the configure command, for example

```
make clean

./configure --with-internal-glib --disable-host-tool \
  --with-pc-path=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig

make
```